# Can't Produce To Kafka When Offline

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I'm trying to produce to kafka using c# and confluent.
This code works just fine when I'm connected To Internet:

```
        ProducerConfig _config = new ProducerConfig();
        _config.BootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";
        using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(_config).Build())
        {
            await producer.ProduceAsync("NewTopic", new Message<Null, string> { Value = "NewTopic" });
            producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            Console.WriteLine("Message Send!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

But When I'm Offline I Get This Error: %3|1639785660.784|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/0]: localhost:9092/0: Failed to resolve 'localhost:9092': The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. (after 4ms in state CONNECT)

Does Anyone Knows Why?

Comment: Does it work with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: No...But works when I'm online

Comment: You don't need internet. Kafka works in airgapped environments. What specific errors do you get?

Comment: I get This Error: %3|1639785660.784|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/0]: localhost:9092/0: Failed to resolve 'localhost:9092': The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.  (after 4ms in state CONNECT)

Comment: Have you reported this error to the confluent-dotnet-kafka Github repo?